# How do I get to the Shuttered Palace?

Tags: fallen-london

I have become quite connected in society, and an acquaintance of mine is suggesting I present myself at the Shuttered Palace. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The most reliable way to gain access to The Shuttered Palace is through the "Open a way to other parts of the City" storylet** that you can find by visiting your lodgings:

[image: Open a way to other parts of the City storylet]

To unlock this option, you need 400 bottles of Greyfields 1882, and 1000 bottles of Greyfields 1879.

A less reliable method is to wait for a "The Ways of the Shuttered Palace" Opportunity card to appear, which will provide you with a few options:

[image: The Ways of the Shuttered Palace storylets]

This card appears for those with a Persuasive skill of 40 to 80, and offers a "day-trip" to The Shuttered Palace for 50 Silk Scrap and permanent access if you are willing to spend 5 Fate (or Nex, as the case may be).

Comment: 400 bottles of Greyfields 1882 (at 4 pennies each) and 1000 bottles of Greyfields 1879 (at 2 pennies each) = 16 echoes + 20 echoes = just 36 echoes. A bit of writing gets you there fast enough.